# I cannot find the error and it shows like this 'Error in ./src/App.js Syntax error: Unexpected token (11:5)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my error

Error in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (11:5)

9 |
10 |   return (

> 11 |     <>
> |      ^
> 12 |
> 13 |         
> 14 |

@ ./src/index.js 13:11-27

Here is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { CssBaseline, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import List from './components/List/List';
import Map from './components/Map/Map';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
   
        <CssBaseline/>
        <Header />
        <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: '100%'}}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
              <List />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
              <Map />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it is my app.js file

Comment: Seems like you have a syntax error at your fragment shorthand `<>` – try replacing that with the longhand notation `<React.Fragment>` and the closing tag `</React.Fragment>`

Comment: What is your react version?

Comment: @LikiCrus version 8.5,5

Comment: @Noob_Gamer I meant React version. Please show your package.json

Comment: @LikiCrus  actually Mikes solution worked for me but I dont understand the problem and how it solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `React.Fragment` instead of `<>`.

I would think your babel plugin doesn't understand `<></>` because of old version.